# How to obtain csrf token from a site?

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to login to https://shopee.co.id/ with curl on linux, and a csrf token is always required when I login with it, right now the csrf token is `gWLIg6tckGVkgWcLkhs2CE5FqRcoeyfr` but it may change in the future. I have tried several things to obtain the csrf token, first I try to see the source code, it doesn't work, there's no csrf token written in the source code, I try the inspect element on chrome developer tools and there's no csrf token either. The token is only present in the application tab on chrome developer tools. How do I find out where I can get the csrf token of that website? I'm sorry for the question, I'm not a programmer, please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the csrf token on this website is just generated randomly from javascript running in the browser from https://cdngarenanow-a.akamaihd.net/shopee/shopee-pcmall-live-id/assets/bundle.fe75b5765ae80df28c1f.js , and has 2 requirements: it must be 32 characters long, and comprised of characters from `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789` - other than that, there seems to be no requirement whatsoever, so just make something up, for example `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`.
the code generating the actual csrf token is

```
    return e || i("csrftoken", e = function(e, n) {
        n = n || "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        for (var a = "", r = 0; r < e; r++) {
            var t = Math.floor(Math.random() * n.length);
            a += n.substring(t, t + 1)
        }
        return a
    }(32), 0), e
}
```

in other words, on this website, you decide what the csrf token is, the server doesn't. to me, this is surprising and highly unusual. (and possibly vulnerable? i'm not sure, haven't given it enough thought)

Comment: Thank you, can you please walk me through on how you were able to find that link to generate the csrf token ?

Comment: @Joe after realizing that this website used a non-standard method, i cleared the browser cache, and set up firefox to connect via Fiddler Proxy, and had Fiddler configured to decrypt TLS connections MITM-style via a fake certificate (that fiddler generated), and recorded logging in on firefox, and checked fiddler for the first reference of the csrf token... with the first reference making no sense (it was the browser sending the server the token, not the other way around), i searched for the first reference to "csrftoken" instead, and found the javascript used to generate the token.